# how to pass SAML attributes from service provider(Salesforce) to Visualforce page Controller

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

SAML response from the identity provides(External) contains the Employee Id as a separate attribute which i need to display in Salesforce VisualForce Page. So help me in passing the attributes from saml response to a VF Page once authenticated via SSO .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a custom SAML handler class? You can generate a template one in SSO settings (bottom of the form, in JIT section) or just look around in documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm or https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_auth_plugin.htm. They both include a `Map<String,String>` to which all attributes from the SAML assertion should be passed.

Once you have them in your code... Not sure if you can do a redirect straight from there but shouldn't be hard to save the attribute in a field on User or wherever you need really. And then query & display it in VF?

If you don't have a custom handler and just use SF built-in piece... If the parameter has right name there's a chance SF will save it for you. You'll have to look at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329069&type=1&mode=1. if your param is in format `User.EmployeeNumber` (or custom field if you need one) - there's hope. If not - probably easiest is to use custom handler.