# Authenticating Azure REST API requests using Azure SSO details within Salesforce

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce

I've setup single sign-on within Salesforce using Microsoft Azure. I've done this within the `Setup > Settings > Identity > Single Sign-On Settings` configuration menu by following [the official tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/salesforce-tutorial). I'm successfully able to log into Salesforce using a user account in my Azure Active Directory, with just-in time provisioning enabled.

I'd like to be able to use the signed in user to then authenticate further requests to different Azure APIs, such as Azure blob storage. Is this possible using this configuration?

My assumption is that during the single sign-on process, Azure is returning some form of code or token to Salesforce which I can then use in future requests to obtain an authentication token for a specific API request. However, I'm not clear on how or where I'd access this code/token (or whether my assumption is actually correct).

Comment: Try to post on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too, you might have more luck

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, you'll need to obtain a new token from Azure. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317828/sso-azure-ad-idp-external-api-callout-from-apex

Answer (score 0):

When I was on the Salesforce end of AAD integration I didn't see anything that would look like session id but then again I'm not Azure guy. Might be something my client disabled.

If you followed that guide SF probably generated for you [a sample Apex class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm) for just-in-time (JIT) handling of logins and creating/updating users based on data it got from AAD.

You could edit this class, sprinkle some `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(attributes));` to see what AAD sent in the SAML assertion. (Or the assertion itself but it'll be base64-encoded from what I remember). Your SF admin will know how to add debug logging to the user you nominated as system user (who this code will be executed as).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63992670/313628 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965058/313628